# How can I increase the period of this PRNG?

Tags: algorithm, random

I found this pseudo random number generator on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) and gave it a try, it's fast and works great for what I intend to use, but I would like it to have a bigger period, is there a way of improving it without making it slower?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long seed = 134515345;

long xorshift_rand(){
    seed ^= seed >> 13;
    seed ^= seed << 17;
    seed ^= seed >> 5;
    return seed;
}


int main()
{
    long start = xorshift_rand();
    long n = 0;
    while (start != xorshift_rand()){
        n++;
        if (n == 0){
            printf("overflow, good.");
        }
    }
    printf("xorshift_rand has a period of %ld", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation *should* have a period of 2<sup>32</sup>-1, but it's broken, so it probably doesn't.  To match the Wikipedia implementation, you need to use 32-bit *unsigned* integers, like this:

```
uint32_t seed = 134515345;

uint32_t xorshift_rand()
{
    seed ^= seed << 13;
    seed ^= seed >> 17;
    seed ^= seed << 5;
    return seed;
}
```

Wikipedia also provides an implementation with period 2<sup>64</sup>-1 using 64-bit integers:

```
uint64_t seed = 134515345;

uint64_t xorshift_rand64()
{
    seed ^= seed << 13;
    seed ^= seed >> 7;
    seed ^= seed << 17;
    return seed;
}
```

Comment: Never mind, much better! Although there seems to be a typo in the `>>>` operator, or my compiler is different.

Comment: "you need to use 32-bit integers and use unsigned shifts" is unclear with code using `int seed`.  I'd expect `uint32_t seed`.  Code as posted has trouble when shifting into the sign bit.

Comment: @Jeacom.  Oh, so sorry.  I thought you were porting it to java.   In C or C++ you should use *unsigned* integer types and `>>`.  I'll fix up the answer so it makes sense for C++

Comment: @chux. My mistake -- I thought we were writing java.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using one of the [xoroshiro](http://prng.di.unimi.it) family of generators.  There are 128, 256, and 1024 bit versions, which should be more than enough of a cycle length for you.  They are among the fastest generators currently available and very high quality (as measured by [BigCrush, a.k.a. TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html)).  Code implementations in several languages can be found on the right side of the xoroshiro page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to moving to a 64-bit xorshift, you can also increase the period of a PRNG by using a Bays-Durham shuffle.